# react's state value not passing to props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am rendering List of users, which I get from Redux store (I store it in variable `data`). Loading of users to Redux is async, that's why it takes a moment and my List has to re-render. I filter this data and save it in **List**'s state and try to send it as prop to **Table** but *it never passes state's value to my table's props*.

```
const getData = data => {...}

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayData: [],
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    return props.data ? { displayData: getData(props.data) } : null;
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return data === undefined && data !== nextProps.data;
  }

  render() {
    const { displayData } = this.state;
    return data ? <Table displayData={displayData} /> : <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ data }) => ({
  data: data.users,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(List);
```

Upper component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { loadData, loadFromStorage } = this.props;
    loadData();
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <Router history={history}>
          <Header history={history} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/list" render={props => <List {...props} />} />
            ...
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = { loadData: LOAD_DATA };

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

It just sets my List component's state and never passes any additional props to Table as they change (I use React extension and I checked props and state)
How can I fix this?
P.S.: I **don't** want this component to re-render every time I get new props

Comment: where is your `react-redux` `connect`? also you need a `mapStateToProps` function. Plus, you need to "load" your data on `componentDidMount` method (Since you have a Redux implementation)

Comment: @Zoti its connected. I just did't think its necessary to include here. It loads data in upper component in componentDidMount

Comment: can you comment out your `constructor` method and initiate your state inside your reducer?

Comment: data is missing both in your render context and outside your class. May be it is  `return displayData ? <Table...` ?

Comment: also try to add some `console.log()`s to see where you "losing" your data

Comment: Where did you `setState()` ?

Comment: @ivica.moke in getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini yeah it's just typo. No difference since it renders old data

Comment: I would suggest to avoid getDerivedStateFromProps and use directly props in render: https://it.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "`data === undefined`", also return `this.state.data !== nextState.data`, do the below way:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.data !== nextState.data;
}
```

I don't know how you set up your reducer's default state for the data property on your reducer file. If the initial state for the data on your reducer file is `{}`, `[]`, or `null`, your code will prevent the component from updating.

Also in your case, your table only takes data from state, not props. After state gets reset, this.props and nextProps may be equal already, so it is better to use this.state.